# Drupal Views page into a menu subitem

Tags: views, routes

Somehow I cannot get the result I want. I have a view that produces a page and I am offered to have this as a menu item in menu of my choice. But what I actually want to achieve is to nest it as a menu item of a MENU ITEM of main menu, such as in:

[main menu] > Downloads > PDF Diagrams

Is that possible at all?

Artur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question,
after creating menu item entry within Views UI
you can go to chosen menu configuration (`admin/structure/menu` for D7) and set parent for your new entry as you would like.

Comment: Many people have the problem Artur is describing. Newcomers to Drupal often think there's only one way to create a menu item (on the node form, or on the Views form). But the authoritative place to create menu items is actually in the menu administration.

Comment: There's one important advantage of assigning menu item via Views UI: if a view disabled or removed, associated menu item deleted automatically.

Comment: Oh, I see, somehow I assumed everything could be done via a given module UI. Now I got the hint, good lesson. Thanks pals!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, and is also the preferred way. You need to set the proper values on the views configuration page under **Page Settings**.

[image: Here]

Make sure that:

- you have everything set up the way you want it under **Menu** (Title, Description, Weight, Parent Menu, etc).
- the view's page path is set up properly. Let's say you wanted as a child of a menu item with an **/admin/custom** path, then you should set the view's path to something like **/admin/custom/myview**